# How do I convert User to Member using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make an info command and I want to get the player's top_role and it can only be accessed using member object. But I only have user object in my info command, so how am I to convert user to member?

Script:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True, name='info')
async def info(ctx, *, user: discord.User):
    member = commands.converter.MemberConverter().convert(user.id)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=str(user.name) + "'s Info.",
        description=f"""
        Name: {user.name}
        Created At: {user.created_at}
        Discriminator: {user.discriminator}
        Display Name: {user.display_name}
        ID: {user.id}
        Is Avatar Animated: {user.is_avatar_animated()}
        Top Role: {member.top_role}
        """
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MemberConverter.convert` also takes `ctx` as an argument, it's also a coroutine so you need to `await` it

```py
member = await commands.MemberConverter().convert(ctx, user.id)
```

You can also simply typehint it to `discord.Member` instead of `discord.User`...

```py
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
```